# insert LAST_INSERT_ID issue

Tags: php, mysql

so I have 2 queries that I'm trying to execute in php. However I get an error. The first id in the first query is auto inc, the second one id in the second query isnt auto inc but it is connected via foreign key to the first one. I want to capture the same id for both of them when the query executes. however this error pops up.

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eangele`.`relationships`, CONSTRAINT `relationships_ibfk_3`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

```
$query = "insert into nodes(id,name,color,type,thumb)".
"values('','$nodename','#EBB056','star','$thumbFile')";
$result = $db -> Execute($query);
$querytwo = "insert into relationships(id,goingto,data)".
"values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$category','')";
$resulttwo = $db -> Execute($querytwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

`'LAST_INSERT_ID()'` is a literal string.  You want to use it without the apostrophes as just `values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),`.

In case that doesn't work, you can use the php function corresponding to the MySQL API you are using to get the last insert ID.  I've also only seen it used with `SELECT`.  I assume it will work with `VALUES` like that, but in case it doesn't you can always do an insert/select:

```
INSERT INTO relationships(id, goingto, data)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ''
```

---

Your queries are vulnerable to injection.  You should parameterize them.

Comment: tried it with and without and it still gave me the same error

Comment: @user1902588 are you sure that the first insert is succeeding?

Comment: yeah the first one works great however I lose the id in the second one. I just want to get the same id for both

Comment: @user1902588 what is the result of `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

Comment: @user1902588 that means that the previous insert either fails or that it does not use an auto_increment column

Comment: It would be very helpful if you broke it down and got the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID` before your second query.

Comment: what sql statement would help me break it down?

Comment: @ExplosionPills how can I use your suggested statement in php? It doesnt work the way you formatted it up there

Comment: @user1902588 in php?  What are you using? ext/mysql? PDO? mysqli?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm using myphpadmin

Comment: @ExplosionPills insert into relationships(id,goingto,data)values(select LAST_INSERT_ID(),'2',''); im using what u gave me but its saying a synax error.

Comment: @user1902588 that's not valid syntax.  Get rid of the values .. do exactly as I do in the query I showed you.

Comment: @ExplosionPills its giving me this error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eangele`.`relationships`, CONSTRAINT `relationships_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: @ExplosionPills it works now! idk what I did, however I works now. Thanks a whole lot man!

Comment: @user1902588 no prob just don't forget to upvote and accept helpful answers